# undefined method `bytesize' for {"COUNT(*)"=>0}:Hash

Tags: mysql, ruby, sinatra

An error is displayed for the client when it is not banned which is:
undefined method `bytesize' for {"COUNT(*)"=>0}:Hash

I use the mysql2 lib

```
post '/mario/login' do
  credentials = CGI.parse request.body.read

  if !credentials.has_key?('username') || !credentials.has_key?('password')
    status 603
    return "MISSING_FIELD"
  end

  results = bans.execute request.ip
  results.each do |row|

    if row['COUNT(*)'] > 0
      status 603
      return "BANNED"
    end

    puts "ok"



  end
end
```

Comment: Your code is trying to return the hash `results` after the function ends. Return with a proper response code/type and it should work.

Comment: I'm really confused as to what `CGI` is doing here. Sinatra should be decoding those arguments for you.

Comment: @kiddorails: ah, indeed.

Comment: @tadman It's request payload (username=root&password=azerty)

Comment: @ken request payload should be auto-decipherable by sinatra in `params` hash. Refer - http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html and search for "query parameters"

Comment: That information should be pre-populated in `params`. Using CGI is a huge throwback that's not necessary.

Comment: @kiddorails Thank you, it works !

Comment: @ken awesome. posted that as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is trying to return the hash `results` after the function ends. Return with a proper response code/type and it should work.

Last line/block in Ruby is returned in any function. In your case, last block is `results.each` which returns back `results` which is not a valid response type for sinatra.